# react-router v5.1.0 Cannot read property 'location' of undefined ,

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to change the background color of my container based on page URL, so if user navigate to URL `'/movie'` it should change the background eg to red  else it should set the background to green

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import Movies from 'pages/Movies/Movies'
import Templates from 'pages/Movies/Templates'
;

export default () => {
    
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Container style={{backgroundColor:location.pathname === '/movies' ? 'red' : 'green'}}>
                    <Main>
                        <App>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path='/templates' component={Templates} />
                                <Route path='/movies'  component={Movies} />
                            
                            </Switch>
                        </App>
                    </Main>
                </Container>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}

const Container = styled.div`
    min-height: 100vh;
    
`;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at useLocation (app.js:54283)
    at app.js:72792
    at renderWithHooks (app.js:37714)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (app.js:40129)
    at beginWork$1 (app.js:41478)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:21756)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:21805)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:21860)
    at beginWork$$1 (app.js:47124)
    at performUnitOfWork (app.js:46032)
```

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: change `const` to `let`. Based on docs here -> https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: no that is not working either

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: @sidthesloth done check update

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to move `BrowserRouter` out of that component. The best is to move it to `index.js` and enclose `<App />`

Comment: can you show it via my ocode your solution I dont get it ?

Comment: remove `<BrowserRouter>` and `</BrowserRouter>` from that file and put it around `<App/>` in `index.js` file

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wozniak-xtocw?file=/src/App.js here is the code

Comment: I was looking for this exactly. Thank you!

Comment: I already did that in my case. Still while testing, this is giving the same error in react-testing-library.

Comment: This works, thanks for the solution. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 12):

You're using `useLocation` outside the components wrapped by the router, in your case the root component (inside `app.js`) is the wrapper of the router component

please check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-fog-0lfrr?file=/src/App.tsx) you could see the difference when you use that hook in `App.tsx` and `QueryReducer` components.

Comment: so what do I need to change though?

Comment: you should move the router to the `index.js` here `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))` to wrap `<App/>`